# Generate guid for HKCU/Software/Microsoft/Internet Explorer/LowR Rights/Elevation Policy

Tags: internet-explorer, registry

I need an answer for work, so the software will not ever go into a public environment. It will be located in a seperate intranet without any access to the internet. I wrote this to address your security concerns.

I have a C# programm which has a custom protocol. This results in a clickable link on a website with this protocol. I have the task to supress the warning popups for launching external popups. Under the location in the headline you can place Key-Value pairs to do so. My problem is that I can't figure out how to generate the guid for the Subkey under which the Key-Value-Pairs are located. The Keys registry will be edited at installation, not in the C# programm. If it is needed, I could also edit the registry with the C# program, but that is not prefered.

Thanks for your efforts,
SchoolGuy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading the Wix-Turorial I learned, that all guids in the registry with a tool named guidgen.exe. It is located (when installed) under:

> C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\bin\NETFX 4.0
>   Tools\guidgen.exe

So when registering my application in the registry, I need to generate a guid with this tool.